# Projectile Shoot three at a time

Tags: c#, unity, projection, touch

In my game there is a bird flying and on touch it throws different artifacts projectile downwards. And these artifacts should hit the containers moving right to left on the screen. Now if user keeps on tapping rapidly it make a line of artifacts and it didn't miss a single container. So what I want to do is to restrict user to throw 3 artifacts at a time and when one of them got destroyed it'll make room for one more. Here is how I'm doing it:

In my `player.cs` I'm using a `static` `int` named `inventory` and then in `Update()` method I've the code where it increment the inventory.

```
if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began){
                OnShoot ();
                inventory++;
                Debug.Log ("Inventory: " + inventory);
            }
```

and in `OnShoot()` I'm checking `if (inventory < 4)` then `Instantiate` otherwise `if (inventory > 4)` set `inventory = 0;`.

 Now in the `artifacts.cs` `if` it hit the container and get `destroyed` or got `destroyed` going out of the bound missing the container it should `Player.inventory--;`

This code works fine but if the user speed of tapping is more then it again started throwing like in a line form as described above.

Comment: Well.. probably resetting `inventory = 0` in `OnShoot` is a mistake? It's kinda hard to answer without the relevant bits of code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should stop incrementing `inventory`, if you don't spawn more projectiles.

Example:

```
if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began){
    if(inventory < 3){ // spawn 3 at max
        OnShoot ();
        inventory++;
    }
}
```

Then decrease `inventory` whenever a projectile gets destroyed. Eg.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if(Player.inventory > 0){
        Player.inventory--;
    }
}
```

Your `OnShoot` should no longer perform any checks against `inventory`, but just spawn a projectile instead...